# how to detect last running thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm running a function using 100 concurrent threads and I want to detect the last running thread of this function, so how can I do that ?

Comment: Do you mean "detect when only 1 of the threads remains"?

Comment: use Log in all thread with different TAG so in log u can see which will execute last

Comment: Yes , when only 1 thread of this function remains, not the last thread of the whole program.

Comment: Do you need to know *which* was the last running thread, or just know when they have all exited? And if so, so so why?

Comment: Why not a synchronized flag?

Comment: no I want to detect exactly the last running one , because the last running one should insert some results into the database.

Comment: @Amirhossein That doesn't answer my question. Try again.

Comment: @EJP: OK , we have lots of threads running same function concurrently but they do not finish their job at the same time , the last running thread of this function should tell me that "I'm the last thread of this function" before it disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Thread.join()` in your main thread for each Thread to complete.

Main thread will not exit until each joined thread is completed.

Comment: The "main" thread in this case would be the thread that spawns the others.

Comment: The Thread API says ->join() Waits for this thread to die. I think he wants to make it wait till all spawned threads die

Answer (score 0):

Use JConsole and monitor the threads.

It will most probabaly available with your JDk

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using CountDownLatch supplied by the JDK. I am assuming here that your function creates the threads, and that you can pass the latch to each of the threads and have them call a method on the latch as they exit. If that is not the case, then you will have to poll a group of threads.

This code is a tweaked version of the example from the JDK documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

```
class Driver { 
  static int numThreads = 10;

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numThreads);

    for (int i=0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
      new Worker(latch).start();
    }

    latch.await(); // blocks until all of the threads complete
  }
}

class Worker extends Thread {
 private final CountDownLatch latch;

 Worker(CountDownLatch latch) {
    this.latch = latch;
 }

 public void run() {
    try {
      System.out.println("do your work here");
    } finally {
      latch.countDown();
    }
 }
}
```